# I want to search and paging at the same time in corda

Tags: corda

I want to search for users by user authority ,

Authority is 「general」「admin」,

α、 This code is search code

```
val states = proxy.vaultQueryBy<UserState>().states
val results = states.filter { it.state.data.authority.toString() == "general" }
```

β、This code is paging code

```
val paging = PageSpecification(1, 10)
val states = proxy.vaultQueryBy<UserState>(paging=paging).states
```

I want to use α and β at the same time
( I want to get the top 10 general users)

Is this possible? Thank you ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really should be as simple as:

```
val paging = PageSpecification(1, 10)
val states = proxy.vaultQueryBy<UserState>(paging=paging).states
val results = states.filter { it.state.data.authority.toString() == "general" }
```

Doesn't that work for you? If so what error are you seeing?

Comment: Thank you for your attention!  
I was able to get the results I'm seeking,  
I thought that this β could only retrieve data that was already paged,